# redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException timeout error

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redis, jedis

I am trying to connect to the redis database residing in remote AWS instance, but I get The JedisConnectionException with timeout when I try to use jedis.hgetAll(key). I am able to retrieve the jedis object though. 
Following is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  String key = "flower";
  Jedis jedis = new Jedis("54.191.60.144", 6379);
  Map<String, String> retrieveMap = jedis.hgetAll(key);
}
```

I am able to display the jedis object which looks like : redis.clients.jedis.Jedis@14fc0eaa

Following is the error:

```
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException:java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:124)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:54)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.sendCommand(Connection.java:77)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.hgetAll(BinaryClient.java:247)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Client.hgetAll(Client.java:189)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.hgetAll(Jedis.java:860)
    at com.main.programs.AverageRedisRetrieval.main(AverageRedisRetrieval.java:44)
```

I would be thankful if somebody could suggest me the resolution. I am able to make the code work with localhost redis connections.

Comment: It is possible that your EC2 instance is unable to talk to the Redis cluster. Check your VPC/security settings.

Comment: I have checked the vpc/security settings. They look good. I have changed a few things in configuration file as well (like commenting out the port binding). Still not able to ping the redis remotely.